# Routing to cloudfront via ELB and to EKS container by path

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I currently have an API backend deployed as a pod inside EKS which I exposed it through using ELB via kubernetes service, and an AngularJS frontend hosted in S3 delivered through Cloudfront, which calls the API.

Is there any way that I could have frontend and backend as **domain.com** and **domain.com/api** respectively with the current setup?

The only other way I could think of is not using Cloudfront to host the AngularJS frontend, but instead dockerize it and deploy as a pod in the same cluster as the backend API but I am just wondering if there is a way that I could use Cloudfront (or any other services or ways) to do some kind path-based proxying to decide which end it should redirect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

DNS records work with domains and subdomains but not paths. This means for `/api` to be interpreted and routed you need a proxy server or an ingress in Kubernetes case.

A simpler approach would be to use `api.domain.com` and `domain.com` then create separate `A` records pointing to your backend and CDN/S3 bucket, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you swap the hosting of your AngularJS frontend from S3 to a Nginx container in EKS you can run your frontend and API behind an ingress controller. You can then target the load balancer created for the ingress from CloudFront with a single DNS record.

**Note** - You will need to configure the cache settings on your API otherwise CloudFront will cache the API output.